# Add attribut select form Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, select, symfony-forms

I would like to add 2 attributs in my select :

```
 ->add('game', EntityType::class, array( 'class'=> Game::Class, 
            'multiple' => false, 
            'expanded' => false,
    ))
```

It's a select with entity, but i want to add another attribut 
who are not in the entities.

I work with Symfony 3.4.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ChoiceType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html%20ChoiceType)

```
->add('yourProp', ChoiceType::class, array(
       'choices'  => array(
           'DisplayOption' => 'SettedValue'
        )
      );
```

Comment: But I can't use my entity at the same time .. ?